# Postcondition for method to find min value of an array

Tags: dafny

I have a function to find the minimun value of an array

```
method arrayMin(a: array<int>) returns (m: int)
  requires a.Length > 0;
  ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] >= m;
{
  var i: nat := 1 ;
  m := a[0] ;
  while (i < a.Length)
    invariant 1 <= i <= a.Length && forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] >= m;
    decreases a.Length - i;
  {
    if (a[i] < m) { m := a[i] ; }
    i := i + 1 ;
  }
}
```

When I try to call

```
  var a := new int[5];
  a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] := 9, 4, 6, 3, 8; 
  var min := arrayMin(a);
  assert min == 3;
```

Dafny is to able to verfiy the assertion. Are the post conditions not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the postcondition is not sufficient.  In English, the postcondition says the following:

> No element in the array `a` is below the value `m` returned.

But, this does not mean `m` has to be a value from the original array!  For example, we can safely modify this line:

```
    if (a[i] < m) { m := a[i] ; }
```

To be this:

```
    if (a[i] < m) { m := a[i] - 1; }
```

And this program will still meet the postcondition.

Therefore to get your assertion to pass, you will a stronger postcondition.  In particular, it needs to ensure that `m` is one of the elements contained in `a`.

Comment: Ater adding the post condition ensures exists k :: 0 <= k < a.Length && a[k] == m; the assertion still can't be verified

Comment: This is the right thing to do.  The problem now is that Dafny cannot put the information together to verify the assertion.  We need to help it.  To get it to verify, I added `assert forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] >= min;` immediately before the assertion.